# Accessing non-persistent variable through NSFetchedResultsController swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is it possible to access non-persistent variables through `NSFetchedResultsController`?

I am having Contact entity created from core-data.
I added one more variable to it which I don’t want to persist, I want this variable only for the period of application live scope, then discard.

```
import CoreData

class Contact: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

    var incomingRequest = false  <———————— temporary variable

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}
```

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to show all the contacts on table view.
When I set incomingRequest, `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn’t trigger `didChangeObject` delegate, that I can understand, it’s obvious.
When I fetch contact from `NSFetchedResultsController` and try to access `incomingRequest`, it always gives me false.

Is there any workaround to get the previously set value of `incomingRequest` by fetching `NSFetchedResultsController`?
Or saving `incomingRequest` too in core data is the only solution?

I know about `transient` property in core data, but I want to use ivars, let's say in future non-persistent properties will get increased.

Thanks in advance :)
Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any workaround to get the previously set value of incomingRequest by fetching `NSFetchedResultsController`?

No, because there isn't any previously set value. If you do the same fetch more than once, you're not guaranteed to get the same object instance. This is especially true if you're doing fetches from different managed object contexts, where you're **guaranteed** to not get the same object. They represent the same instance in the persistent store, but they're not the same object in memory.

So, you set `incomingRequest` to `true` on one object, but then you use your fetched results controller and get a different object. But you haven't set a value of `incomingRequest` on this other object, so it gets the default value.

Whether to include `incomingRequest` in your data model depends on what that value means and how you use it. That might be the right answer. You might prefer to do something like keep a set of `NSManagedObjectID`s, as the incoming request collection, so you could always find out if a fetched object should be considered as having an incoming request.

Comment: Thanks very much for answer, I forgot to try NSManagedObjectIDs option, now I tried it and it worked for me! Now I am storing NSManagedObjectIDs of all contacts which are incoming requests in an array, and iterating through this array. Thanks again (y)